# Вывод таблицей и изменение данных

Tags: android

У меня есть база данных, из нее нужно вывести данные в таблицу (ну или чтобы "это" выглядело, как таблица). Примерно вот так (извините за кривизну, рисовал в paint'e):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы при нажатии и удержании линии — она закрашивалась (на время удержания):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вызывалось контекстное меню, в котором предлагается изменить или удалить запись. При выборе пункта как-то передавались значения полей (текст из них) в метод, который будет это обрабатывать.

После удаления, эта линия должна пропасть (желательно не перезагружая всю таблицу, так как там могут быть тысячи записей), но цифры изменится, чтобы записи были прономерованы (если с цифрами никак нельзя реализовать — можно убрать их, но это крайне нежелательно). А, при изменении, текст в записях обновится (опять желательно не перезагружать всю таблицу).

Данные для изменения буду передавать в диалог, пользователь будет их менять, а потом они вернутся обновленные (в БД они будут добавлены сразу), при удалении — сразу удалю из БД. Для этих действий мне нужно получить значения полей.

После загрузки таблицы данные могут (и будут) добавляться и нужно добавлять новые линии сверху.

---

Через что можно реализовать то, что мне нужно (идей совсем нет), не заставляя приложение грузится минуту, после любого действия (количество записей может быть вплоть до несколько тысяч)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать сделать с помощью списка с кастомным адаптером.
Чтобы список имел вид таблицы - делаем свой кастомный xml шаблон айтема списка.

Посмотрите [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/arrayadapter.php) и [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/82-urok42-spisok-listview)

**UPD:**

Оптимизация списка [тут](http://androiddocs.ru/pattern-viewholder-v-realizacii-spiska-listview/)

Comment: Тогда, при изменении\удалении, будем перезагружаться весь список и зависание гарантировано (ну или сон, если в методе).

Comment: @bukashka101 обновил ответ, посмотрите. Можно оптимизировать список с помощью холдера. И тогда можно будет хоть овер 100 000 записей, ибо будут подгружаться постепенно.

Comment: Я в шоке.... Вывод 5 000 тысяч записей — секунда, даже на эмуляторе.

Comment: @bukashka101 реализовали с помощью холдера ?

Comment: Да. Создал проект, скопировал код с сайта, но изменил количество элементов до 5 000 и активировал все кнопкой. Выгрузка с БД затормозит процесс, но скорость выгрузки офигенная! Завтра буду делать кастомный адаптер.

Comment: @bukashka101 рад помочь:)

Comment: RecyclerView давно для этого есть, а ListView в прошлом

Comment: @georgehardcore, именно так. На сколько я знаю, RecyclerVIew более современнее, чем ListView и больше возможностей. Но с ним не работал, по сему и не написал в ответе его..

Comment: Я наоборот, сейчас очень плотно работаю с RecyclerView. И задолбался уже, если честно.
В крации могу сказать, что если Вам не особо нужна красота и анимация, лучше используйте ListView. Всё что вы хотите сделать, делается с ListView и не перегружать все данные, при изменении значений БД, тоже возможно, если правильно использовать Cursor.
насчет производительности (ViewHolder) советуют использовать в любом случае просто, на примере с RecyclerView он обязателен. RecyclerView очень сыроват, Очень. Советую воздержаться пока от него. ИМХО

Comment: RecyclerView был сыроват, когда его только добавили, когда изучал его тоже многое раздражало, особенно отсутствие OnItemClickListener, но сейчас, вообще не могу понять почему можно задолбаться с ним ViewHolder, LayoutManager, ItemAnimator все замечательно и просто

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei интересно мнение..

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, что Вы подразумеваете под фразой "если правильно использовать Cursor"? Как его можно неправильно использовать?